# Prove that if G is nearly strongly connected there exists vertex such that every vertex is reachable

Tags: graph-theory

Given a directed graph $G = (V, E)$, the strongly connected components graph $G^{SCC}$ of $G$ is the directed graph defined by $V^{SCC} = \{C \mid C\ \text{is a}\ SCC\ \text{of}\ G\}$ and $E^{SCC} = \{(C_i, C_j) \mid \exists(u, v) \in E\ \text{where}\ u \in C_i, v \in C_j\}$. $G$ is nearly strongly connected if for each pair of vertices $s, t \in V$, either there exists a path from $s$ to $t$ or a path from $t$ to $s$.

Prove that if directed graph $G = (V, E)$ is nearly strongly connected then there exists
a vertex $x \in V$ such that every vertex in $V$ is reachable from $x$.

How would I go about proving this?

I have tried drawing a diagram and saw that

```
    (+)
  /    \ 
(+)    (+)
  \
    \ 
      \ 
       (+)
```

the nodes connect criss cross and double everytime you add any.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: choose $x$ to be a vertex which has paths to as many other vertices as possible, and show that if $x$ doesn't have a path to $y$ then $y$ can't have a path to $x$.

Comment: how would i show that no other vertex can have a path to x? I don't seem to understand that part.

Comment: If $x$ has a path to $z$ and $y$ has a path to $x$, what does that imply about $x$ and $z$? Actually I notice I was very unclear about what I meant by "other vertex", will edit to clarify.

Comment: oh i see what you mean so I use proof by contradiction?